# Query Django's HStoreField values using LIKE

Tags: django, python-3.x, hstore

I have a model with some HStoreField attributes and I can't seem to use Django's ORM [HStoreField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield) to query those values using LIKE.

When doing `Model.objects.filter(hstoreattr__values__contains=['text'])`, the queryset only contains rows in which `hstoreattr` has any value that matches `text` **exactly**.

What I'm looking for is a way to search by, say, `te` instead of `text` and those same rows be returned as well. I'm aware this is possible in a raw PostgreSQL query but I'm looking for a solution that uses Django ORM.

Comment: Could you share your solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check value of particular key in every object if it contains 'te', you can do:

```
Model.objects.filter(hstoreattr__your_key__icontains='te')
```

If you want to check if **any** key in your hstore field contains 'te', you will need to create your own lookup in django, because by default django won't do such thing. Refer to [custom lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/) in django docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, you cannot filter in values. If you want to filter in values, you have to pass a column and value you are referencing to. When you want it to be case insensitive use `__icontains`.

Although you cannot filter by all values, you can filter by all keys. Just like you showed in your code.

If you want to search for 'text' in all objects in key named let's say 'fo' - just do smth like this:

`Model.objects.filter(hstoreattr__icontains={'fo': 'text'})`

Comment: Yep, as I mentioned in the question, I'm aware I can do this. What I need is a way to do `Model.objects.filter(hstoreattr__values__icontains=['te'])` and get the row which attribute is `{'fo': 'text'}` as well. It's possible to do this in Postgres using LIKE, so I'll be really sad if I really can't do this using Django's ORM :(

Comment: I don't think so. If you want it really badly, you can take all of your hstore keys and iterate through them, later chain your querysets, and take distinct objects. But that can be time consuming